# Pip won't let me install anything

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Just setting up my python environments here. An absolute newb if you must say.

Background information: Currently at a place that requires a proxy to be set. I do this by using the Manual Proxy Settings in Wondows Settings.

I did go ahead and add http_proxy, https_proxy, and socks_proxy to my system variables as follows
HTTP_PROXY
http://10.8.0.1:8080
HTTPS_PROXY
https://10.8.0.1:8080
ALL_PROXY
socks5://10.8.0.1:8080

Any and everytime I type in to install any package through pip, I write the command "pip install package_name" on my powershell terminal, I get the error,

```
 Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 180, in _main 
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 204, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 318, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 127, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 473, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 341, in resolve
    name, crit = self._merge_into_criterion(r, parent=None)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 172, in _merge_into_criterion
    if not criterion.candidates:
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\structs.py", line 139, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 143, in __bool__
    return any(self)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 129, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 30, in _iter_built
    for version, func in infos:
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 258, in iter_index_candidate_infos
    result = self._finder.find_best_candidate(
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 879, in find_best_candidate
    candidates = self.find_all_candidates(project_name)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 824, in find_all_candidates
    page_candidates = list(page_candidates_it)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\sources.py", line 134, in page_candidates
    yield from self._candidates_from_page(self._link)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 783, in process_project_url
    html_page = self._link_collector.fetch_page(project_url)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 512, in fetch_page
    return _get_html_page(location, session=self.session)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 422, in _get_html_page
    resp = _get_html_response(url, session=session)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 120, in _get_html_response
    resp = session.get(
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 555, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\session.py", line 449, in request
    return super().request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\adapter.py", line 53, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 696, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 964, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connection.py", line 359, in connect
    conn = self._connect_tls_proxy(hostname, conn)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connection.py", line 500, in _connect_tls_proxy
    return ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 432, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 474, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\ssl.py", line 997, in _create
    raise ValueError("check_hostname requires server_hostname")
ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname
```

What am I supposed to do?
Another answer on stackoverflow which I am assuming is for the same problem is to downgrade urlib3 using "pip install urllib3==1.25.11" but I literally can't use pip because all I'd get is the same error.

I have since also tried to install and reinstall python. Even went from 3.9.5 to 3.8.10 but the problem still persists.

Please help

Comment: Are you sure the HTTPS proxy is also https://? Could you try setting both HTTPS and HTTP proxies to http://...?

Comment: Or `socks5://` like `ALL_PROXY`…

Comment: Did you try `pip` with `pip install --proxy=https://[username:password@]proxyserver:port somepackage` ?

Comment: @KlimBim yes, I did. Same error

Comment: @AKX That actually worked. Thanks a lott!!
I just knew what the proxy ip and port were and I was told to put http, https and socks5 respectively under the environment variables somewhere on stackoverflow and that is exactly where I apparently went wrong.

Comment: @ANIMO Glad I could help. I made that comment an answer you can accept :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(To make my comment an answer:)

The HTTPS proxy should probably not be using the https:// protocol itself, so

```
HTTP_PROXY=http://10.8.0.1:8080
HTTPS_PROXY=http://10.8.0.1:8080
```

should be the more correct environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

I also found the answer that suggested to downgrade urllib3==1.25.11.
As I understand, You can try to install urllib3 from local.

```
pip install <path-to-package>
```

[here](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/archive/refs/tags/1.25.11.zip) to download package

Comment: Although pip install <package> did not really work. I did manage to install urlib3 v1.25.11 using the setup.py but the problem still persists. Exact same error message.

Answer (score -2):

Have you created a local environment using something like

> python.exe -m venv env

? It seems like you are trying to install packages on the main python install